# SQL string count

Tags: sql

I have a table in SQL. I have a column named `CarMakes`, it has the following contents:

```
Mercedes, BMW
Range Rover
Mazda, Toyota, Honda
```

I want to know how to return a number of `CarMakes` in each row.

Returned value should be 2, 1 and 3 respectively.

Comment: values for `CARMAKES` are separated by a comma?

Comment: And what kind of SQL server are you using?

Comment: Yes, the values are separated by comma

Comment: Do ***not*** store multiple values (delimited by something) in a single column. That is a ***very*** bad idea. You should re-design your data model. Then the query will be *very* simple. See here for more information: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3653462/330315

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a MySQL-based answer, so it may be inappropriate for your case if you're using something else. This assumes the values are comma-separated and in the same column (quite an assumption :) ):

```
SELECT car, (LENGTH(car)-LENGTH(REPLACE(car, ',', ''))+1) AS 'Counts'
FROM CarMakes
```

I'm sure this will run into issues somewhere, but it may work if your situation doesn't contain random commas. You can see the SQLFiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/282c4).

Comment: @YerdenAbsattar: so, is your engine MySql?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(CarMakes), CarMakes FROM cartable ORDER BY CarMakes ASC
```

Comment: Your solution assumes `CarMakes` is normalized and it's not. The query would return `(1, "Mercedes, BMW"),  (1, "Range Rover"), (1,"Mazda, Toyota, Honda")`.

Comment: @Neolisk, that wasn't defined (or clear) in the original question.  Thank goodness for updates and edits.  As mentioned by others, the table should be normalized, making this the proper way to query.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming T-SQL / MS SQL Server, you have two options:

1. [String.Split](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647/split-string-in-sql) - count array elements.
2. [Find occurrence of character in String](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2010/08/16/sql-server-finding-the-occurrence-of-character-in-string/) - count commas.